# Index position in parent of element as property css

Tags: css

I have a list of elements:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">A sample</li>
  <li class="item">B sample</li>
  <li class="item">C sample</li>
  <li class="item">D sample</li>
</ul>
```

And i want to get element position in list and every next element in this list size up font to +10px.
It should looks like this: `font-size: calc(10px * n);` but this thing doesnt work.

How can i use this `n` value as property in css using only css?

Comment: Use SASS to generate the code, there is no such thing in CSS

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically read `n` as a variable in CSS but you can use CSS variables to minimise the amount you write and keep the behaviour controlled in a single property:

```css
.item {
  font-size: calc(10px * var(--n, 1));
}

.item:nth-child(1) { --n: 1; }
.item:nth-child(2) { --n: 2; }
.item:nth-child(3) { --n: 3; }
.item:nth-child(4) { --n: 4; }
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/L7atcjbg/